# wso2 ApiManager ApiStatusObserver

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, observers

i have to intercept APi Publisher events into wso2 ApiManager wso2am-2.1.0.
I wrote an Observer like this..

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.model.API;
import org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.model.APIStatus;
import org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.observers.APIStatusObserver;

public class CustomApiObserver implements APIStatusObserver{
  private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(CustomApiObserver.class);

@Override
public boolean statusChanged(APIStatus previous, APIStatus current, API api) 
    {
    log.info("API status updated from: " + previous.getStatus() + " to: " +
            current.getStatus() + " for the API: " + api.getId().getApiName() + " (" + api.getId().getVersion() + ")");
    PrintWriter writer;
    try {
    writer = new PrintWriter("/opt/CustomApiObserver.log", "UTF-8");
    writer.println("The first line");
    writer.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;       
 }  
}
```

packaged as jar and copied into [AM_HOME]/repository/lib and [AM_HOME]/repository/components/lib.

I don't found if the observer should be registered.
There are other configs for enable the Observer?

I googled but I haven't found resources on carbon observers deployments.

wso2server run as root, and i didn't find any logs into carbon dashboard or file wroted, even error traces, as if it doesn't fired.

Thank you all.